# HTML: clicking on different tab maintains the position on the page, but I want it to scroll up

Tags: html, css

On my website, I have buttons that link to different pages via nav tabs. When the buttons are clicked, the view maintains the position (ex: half-way scrolled through the page) on the new page. I would like it to scroll to the top of the new tab view (rather than just stay in the middle) but can't figure out a way to do this. Anyone know a way here?

Comment: I would suggest adding relevant code to your answer and possible a fiddle or link to the live site.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you should add some code.  But if you're changing tabs via javascript add this bit:

```
 window.scroll(0,0);
```

That will reposition the window to the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Input this JQuery code on the page you need to scroll up

```
   var body = $("html, body");
body.stop().animate({scrollTop:0}, '500', 'swing', function() {
});
```